# replace a string of a div that have content in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress search form that give me the text of buttons, and I don't want it. So I tried to remove it manually because all the texts are the same.
I used :

```
$("#search_content").text().replace(/\ All WebinarPrevious WebinarNext Webinar /g,".")
```

It give me the good text ... but when I try to add it like that :

```
$("#search_content").text($("#search_content").text().replace(/\ All WebinarPrevious WebinarNext Webinar /g,"."));
```

It erase all my HTML tag and break the display.
Is there a way to change only the text ?
Here is the important part of my html structure :

```
<div id="search_content">
  <ul>
   <li>
      <h3><a href="#">Webinar 1</a></h3>
          /*some text*/ All WebinarPrevious WebinarNext Webinar  /*some text*/                
   </li>
   <li>
      <h3><a href="#">Webinar 2</a></h3>
         /*some text*/ All WebinarPrevious WebinarNext Webinar /*some text*/
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is when you are using text it is reading as text and put as text. The `text()` method sets or returns the text content of the selected elements. You have to use html to preserve html formatting

```
$("#search_content").html($("#search_content").html().replace(/\ All WebinarPrevious WebinarNext Webinar /g,"."));
```

This will do the trick.